# puppet facter last run status

Tags: linux, puppet, ansible

Is it possible for facter to show the last status of puppet runs?

typically puppet stores the result in YAML format in

/var/lib/puppet/state/last_run_report.yaml

any way to get these values as a facter?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you would need to write a [custom fact](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/latest/fact_overview.html) that just reads the contents of the file and returns it as a (long!) string.

Using large fact values like that may be a Bad Idea, your mileage may vary.